# I got trouble with eval() function in php?

Tags: php

i have searched this function on google a lot. However, i can't understand this function clearly.
i have a example:

```
<?php
//eval dangerous to use
$motto="lksdfasdkf";
$str= "<h1>Welcome</h1><?php echo $motto;?><br/>"; 
echo $str.'<br />';  //result: welcome
eval("?>"." $str"."<?php echo $motto;");  //error
echo $str;
?>
```

Comment: what you want output?

Comment: Worked fine for me. Output was `Welcome


Welcome
lksdfasdkf
lksdfasdkf
Welcome` some in `<h1>` text just as shown in your code.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Then you don't have error reporting enabled. See this demo: https://eval.in/116010

Answer (score 2):

`eval()` takes a string and evaluates it as PHP code. Here are some important points to note:

1. `eval()` takes **PHP Code** as it's argument -- not mixed HTML markup. Currently, you're passing a string containing HTML markup.
2. You don't need to add `<?php ... ?>` tags in the string. `eval()` already knows the argument is going to be PHP code (it's supposed to be), so you don't need to tell it

Here's a very short example:

```
$motto = "lksdfasdkf";    
$str = 'echo $motto;';     
eval($str); // => lksdfasdkf
```

Here, the string `$str` contains the literal string `echo $motto;`, which is a valid statement in PHP. When you call `eval($str);` the string gets evaluated as PHP code. In this case, it will echo the contents of the variable.

Note that this wouldn't work if you use double-quotes instead:

```
$motto = "lksdfasdkf";
$str = "echo $motto;"; 
eval($str);
```

If you have error reporting enabled, then you'll get the following error:

> Notice:  Use of undefined constant lksdfasdkf - assumed 'lksdfasdkf' in

The reason is that variables are **not** parsed when they're wrapped in single-quotes. When you use double-quotes to define your variable, the variable value gets interpolated into the resulting string, meaning `$str` will contain the literal string `echo lksdfasdkf;` -- which is **not valid PHP code**. The solution is to escape the dollar character to avoid it being interpreted as a variable:

```
$motto = "lksdfasdkf";
$str = "echo \$motto;"; 
eval($str); // => lksdfasdkf
```

Comment: @Fred-ii-: That's probably because you don't have error reporting enabled. See this demo: https://eval.in/116010

Comment: You're right Amal, now it did throw `Notice: Use of undefined constant lksdfasdkf - assumed 'lksdfasdkf' in...` error after adding error reporting. **+1** ;-) I had a feeling about the OP's single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

**[eval](https://www.php.net/eval) — Evaluate a string as PHP code**    - your code also working fine

try

```
$motto="lksdfasdkf";
    $str= "<h1>Welcome</h1>$motto<br/>"; 
    echo $str.'<br />';  //result: welcome
    eval("\$str = \"$motto\";");
    echo $str;
```

Comment: why i can't use like that? eval("\$str = \"$motto\";"); => $str="lksdfasdkf";    so eval("?>"." $str"."<?php echo $motto;"); => ?> <h1>Welcome</h1>$motto<br/> <?php echo "lksdfasdkf";